# simple loop is not working properly

Tags: loops

```
int f,b;
int x=0;
int m=502;
int n=3;
int r=1;
int main()
{
while(1){
  if(m>n)
{
f=m/n;  
  b=f*n;
  r=m-b;
printf("1");
  }
  if(m<n)
  {
f=n/m;
   b=f*m;
   r=n-b;
printf("2");
  }

if(r==0)
   {
printf("m=%i n=%i b=%i f=%i",m,n,b,f);
return(1);
   }
 if(m>n && m>r)
{
printf("4");
  m=r;
}
if(n>m && n>r)
{
printf("5");
n=r;
}}
}
```

So if I edit out while(1), the program executes correctly once, but I want it to loop back and whether it is for(;;) or while (1) or while (x==0) the terminal (or cmd) window is not printing anything and not terminated

And nothing from all the printf i stuck in each condition is printed so that means that none of those conditions are satisfied by my m and n !!!
so i tried this  while (1){ printf("0"); the rest of the code }

And it prints 013400000000 till i terminate
  thank you very much 
i use kali linux gcc-4.7.2

Comment: Please take care to format your code properly, it's completely unreadable as it is.

Comment: My eye feels pain. Please format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int f,b; 
int x=0;  
int m=502;
int n=3;
int r=1;
int main()
{
printf("in main\n");
int loop=0;
while(1)
{
    printf("in while %d %d %d\n",m,n,r);

    printf("if(m>n) %d\n\n",m>n);
    if(m>n)
    {
       f=m/n;  
       b=f*n;
       r=m-b;
       printf("m>n 1\n");
    }
    printf("if(m<n) %d\n\n",m<n);
    if(m<n)
    {  
       f=n/m;
       b=f*m;
       r=n-b;
       printf("m<n 2\n");
    }
    printf("if(r==0) %d\n\n",r);
    if(r==0)
    { 
       printf("m=%i n=%i b=%i f=%i\n",m,n,b,f);
       return(1);
    }
    printf("if(m>n && m>r) %d\n\n",m>n && m>r);
    if(m>n && m>r)
    {
       printf("m>n && m>r 4\n");
       m=r;
    }
    printf("if(n>m && n>r) %d\n\n",n>m && n>r);
    if(n>m && n>r)
    {
       printf("n>m && n>r 5\n");
       n=r;
    }
    if(loop++ == 10)
    break;
 }
}
```

Your loop was working fine, but all the `conditional if` statements are returning `0`,which is why your `printf` statements in the condition never executed, after the first iteration of the loop.

I did not try to understand whatever you are trying to achieve. But, I reckon, that you are new to programming.

**Word of Advice**

Always, use `printf` statements, when ever you are having trouble with loops, as I did. Looking at the `loop variables` or `any other variables` that are undergoing change will help track the `execution flow` of the loop better.

Comment: first things first, thank you very much for reediting the code

Comment: @user3566929  accept answers if they answered your question. and upvote answers if you think they helped you.

Comment: first things first, thank you very much for bothering to reedit the code and your code works flawlessly.... now the problem is if i  remove all the printf statements between all the if conditions, the loop gets stuck again after the first iteration, it is obviously doing something and i can`t understand to what is it returning, i know the if statement is just a branching or jump instruction.....so could you elaborate a little more...thank you

Comment: i am sorry power short happened

Comment: `m` and `n` are equal to `1` in the `second iteration`, therefore the first two if conditions are `false` and check the value of `r` to know why exactly the remaining conditions are `false`.

Comment: @user3566929 if I answered your question upvote or accept it.

Comment: well, i tried to sanity check it again and it turned out to be a very stupid code...thanks again